# Error prompted when using HMS IAP refund API

Tags: in-app-purchase, huawei-developers, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-iap

I am trying to implement the HMS IAP refund API on my server side, but the API call doesn't work 100% of the time. I'm getting error: responseCode:"12"

This is the sample code I used.

```
POST /sub/applications/v2/purchases/returnFee
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Authorization: Basic QVQ6Q1YzQ1NPbVlBaGwrZUtRWExtMTBVV2pyWXZHTVF4MmYvcVMya1B0ZElLY3UwaFJrdFNTMmxwdk1FQkIyYldXWGt0REVaR3I4UjFUTTRLMVlmNXdwWU80RG04THdXQWxjaFhEYjBMUjBNTUJtWnFYcGFtazc3THN3UnFJbkhHK28xekdqRzNSMg==
Accept: application/json
Content-Length: 171
{
  "purchaseToken": "00000173741056a37eef310dff9c6a86fec57efafe318ae478e52d9c4261994d64c8f6fc8ea1abbdx5347.5.3089",
  "subscriptionId": "1581789719266.D40972AC.3089"
}
```

The weird part is that some refunds work and some don't. Not sure what's going on here. Could someone help me with this issue? Is it possible to use Huawei console to issue refund and confirm it instead?

Comment: This API refunds only the last fee of a specified subscription. The responseCode 12 also means the order in this query may be a historical order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot issue refund or do the confirmation through HW AGC. You will need to  contact Huawei regional operation personal to manually handle it.

Adding IAP refund API into your app is probably the most direct way. As for your refund error "12", it means: The order does not exist. The order in this query may be a historical order. The whole list of error code is [Here](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-References-V5/server-error-code-0000001050166248-V5):
[image]

For more HMS IAP Refund information on [Subscription refund](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-References-V5/api-refund-subscription-fee-0000001050986131-V5)

and info. on [Consumable/Non-consumable](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-References-V5/api-cancel-or-refund-record-0000001050746117-V5)